# Specific String replacement

Tags: python, regex

I have the string `1km N of Piedmont, California` and I want to replace the distance value `1` with the word equivalent (`one`), but only if the number is below 10 (in this case it is). I also want to replace `km` with `kilometre` as well as `N` with `North`, `E` with `East`, etc.

What would be the most Pythonic way to approach this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you put your code?

Comment: I would suggest doing this by using regex matching groups. However, beeing somekind of taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut, it should work.

Comment: You can use Regular Expressions for this, but you need to be careful with your regex design so you don't eg accidentally replace 'km' in the the middle of a place name.

Comment: @Ymartin I haven't tried anything yet. Considering regex or splitting the numbers and letters up with string's digits class. Just wanted to see what you guys would recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression substitution should work nicely using a function with a dictionary lookup:

```
def replace(match):
    d = {'1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': 'three', '4': 'four', '5': 'five', '6': 'six', '7': 'seven', '8': 'eight', '9': 'nine', 'N': 'North', 'E': 'East', 'S': 'South', 'W': 'West'}
    source = match.group(1).strip()
    return d.get(source, source) + ' '

text = '1km N of Piedmont, California'
print re.sub(r'(\d+ *(?=km)|[NESW]\s+(?=of))', replace, text)
```

This would display something like:

```
one km North of Piedmont, California
```

**Update** - To deal with `kilometres` the script can be modified as follows:

```
def convert(text):
    def replace(match):
        d = {'1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': 'three', '4': 'four', '5': 'five', '6': 'six', '7': 'seven', '8': 'eight', '9': 'nine', 'N': 'North', 'E': 'East', 'S': 'South', 'W': 'West'}
        source = match.group(1).strip()

        if 'km' in source:
            source = source.split("km")[0].strip()
            return "{} kilometre{}".format(d.get(source, source), '' if source == '1' else 's')
        else:
            return d.get(source, source) + ' '

    return re.sub(r'(\d+ *km|[NESW]\s+(?=of))', replace, text)  

print convert('1 km N of Piedmont, California')
print convert('1km N of China')
```

Giving:

```
one kilometre North of Piedmont, California
one kilometre North of China
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! I'm not too familiar with Regex, is there an easy way to alter this to return "one kilometre" when the value is 1 otherwise return "x kilometres"?

Comment: I have added a second version for you to try. Hopefully you find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Martin! I'm trying to use this in a class (I'm still learning Python so I apologize for any dumb errors I may be overlooking) but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's what I'm doing https://github.com/WAGGNews/WAGG-Earthquake-Bot/blob/regex/bot/english.py#L21

Comment: Seems ok to me, I tried `eng = English({'features': [{'properties':{'place':'test 1 km N of China'}}]}); print eng.place()`

Comment: I tried it in a dummy project and couldn't get the same result. I threw the dummy code on a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/trommel/066930ecf81854ee6dfe) if you could take a look. Thanks :)

Comment: Try changing to this line: `source = source.split("km")[0].strip()`

Comment: That fixes everything except for km/kilometre, which it removes altogether: `one  North of China`

Comment: Your Gist code is still showing the old version? The code above works fine for the two examples.

Comment: The code you have is subtly different, and that causes your bug. One line is in the wrong place.

Comment: Ah, my bad. It works now. Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: You are welcome. You can click on the tick next to the answer to accept it and get a badge.